# Hidden .index.php file not being recognized by Apache

Tags: php, html, apache

I have a page that indexes the directory and outputs the files on an html table, in order for the table to look good I have to hide files that shouldn't be listed like php / js / css / favicon / htaccess files, everything is working properly until I hide my index.php and then my default page reverts to apache's disgusting default index page.

My .htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex .index.php
```

My 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost (removed)>
    ServerName  (removed)
    ServerAlias  (removed)
    ServerAdmin  (removed)
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
<Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
 </Directory>


# Other directives here
 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The whole page works fine as long as my index.php page isn't hidden with a dot, my css/js/favicon work fine hidden and work, just not .index.php. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

edit: if I go to https://example.com/.index.php the page loads fine but https://example.com is still the default apache index page

Comment: Check this out, it helps you configure apache to not idnore `.` files. https://serverfault.com/questions/245922/how-to-configure-apache-to-view-hidden-files

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work for me, it just updated apache's default index page and started listing the hidden files.